# Expected 3 arguments, but got 2

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, react, ms-graph-client

I'm working on a WebPart, which has a form and a button. On button click write items in a SharePoint  List. So, the button click is my last step, but the buton does not work.
I get everytime:

> Expected 3 arguments, but got 2.

And bellow my code

```
 <DefaultButton className={styles.button} onClick={() => this.addListItems(this.state.data, this.state.selectedDepartmentOptions)}> Eintragen </DefaultButton>

 private addListItems = (user: MicrosoftGraph.User, selectedDepartmentOptions: IDropdownOption[], destinations: IDropdownOption): void =>  {

const { selectedRubrikOptions } = this.state;
const departmentKey = user.department;
var isTerminvergabeChecked = (document.getElementById('terminvergabe') as HTMLInputElement | null).checked;
var isHotlineChecked = (document.getElementById('hotline') as HTMLInputElement | null).checked;
let selectedDepartmentText = "";

for (let i = 0; i < selectedDepartmentOptions.length; i++) {
  const option = selectedDepartmentOptions[i];

  if (option.key === departmentKey) {
    selectedDepartmentText = option.text;
    console.log(selectedDepartmentText);
    break;
  }
}

if(selectedRubrikOptions === ""){
  alert('Bitte das Pflichtfeld beachten!');

}else{
  sp.web.lists.getByTitle('Laufkundschaft')
  .items.add({
    'Rubrik': selectedRubrikOptions,
    'Au_x00df_enstellen': selectedDepartmentText,
    'Terminvergabe': isTerminvergabeChecked,
    'Hotline': isHotlineChecked,
  })
  .then(()=> alert("Die Daten wurden erfolgreich gespeichert!"));

}
```

Anyone, any solution? I seat since 2 hours whith this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You defined your function to recieve 3 arguments :

```
 private addListItems = (user: MicrosoftGraph.User, selectedDepartmentOptions: IDropdownOption[], destinations: IDropdownOption)
```

1. User
2. selectedDepartmentOptions
3. destinations

while you called this function on button click

```
onClick={() => this.addListItems(this.state.data, this.state.selectedDepartmentOptions)
```

1. User
2. selectedDepartmentOptions

you should also pass the "**destination**" argument, or just delete it from your function definition, because i cannot see where you used this argument inside the function :

```
 private addListItems = (user: MicrosoftGraph.User, selectedDepartmentOptions: IDropdownOption[])
```

Comment: Thank you! I havenow an other error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IDropdownOption[]'.  Do you have any idea?

Comment: yes, in your function definition you specified that the paramter selectedDepartmentOptions is an array, while you are passing this.state.selectedDepartmentOptions is a string